# Question about the Axioms of Neighborhoods in a Topology

Tags: general-topology

In the section "Topology from neighbourhoods" in the Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_(mathematics), it states

A neighbourhood system on $\displaystyle X$ is the assignment of a filter $\displaystyle N(x)$ of subsets of $\displaystyle X$ to each $\displaystyle x$ in $\displaystyle X$, such that

(1) the point $\displaystyle x$ is an element of each $\displaystyle U$ in $\displaystyle N(x)$

(2) each $\displaystyle U$ in $\displaystyle N(x)$ contains some $\displaystyle V$ in $\displaystyle N(x)$ such that for each $\displaystyle y$ in $\displaystyle V$, $\displaystyle U$ is in $\displaystyle N(y)$.

What is the intuition/ meaning of (2), and isn't (2) trivially satisfied with V = U?

Comment: The last axiom is to link neighbourhoods to the topology: every neighbourhood contains an *open* neighbourhood. Without it, there is no coherence between the filters $N(x)$ for different $x$..

Answer (score 2):

Something like the second clause is needed in order to ensure that the neighborhoods of different points are compatible in the sense that they are actually consistent with a topology on $X$. The specifics must also take into account the fact that we don’t require a neighborhood of a point to be an open set, but we do require the point to be in its interior. Here’s an example to show why (2) isn’t trivially satisfied with $V=U$; with luck the example will also give some insight into why we need clause (2).

Let the space be $\Bbb R$ with the usual topology; for each $x\in\Bbb R$ we then have

$$N(x)=\{M\subseteq X:x\in(a,b)\subseteq M\text{ for some }a,b\in\Bbb R\}$$

Thus, $U=[0,2]$ is a nbhd of $1$, since $1\in(0,2)\subseteq[0,2]$. It is not true, however, that $[0,2]$ contains a nbhd of each point of $[0,2]$, since it does not contain any nbhd of $0$ or of $2$. It **does**, however, contain a nbhd of each point of $V=(0,2)$, which is also a nbhd of $1$.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the "intuition" of (2) is that it is satisfied by the usual notion
of neighbourhoods in topological spaces.

In this set-up, neighbourhood is not synonymous with "open neighbourhood".
So in the usual topology on $\Bbb R$, take $x=0$, $U=[-1,1]$. If we could
take $V=U$ consider $y=1$. But $U$ is not a neighbourhood of $1$; $U\notin N(1)$.
So we can't take $V=U$ in general.